# Android | adding V8 reference to android studio project

Tags: android, v8

I am interesting in using the V8 chrome javascript engine, but going through their documentations i couldn't find a way to reference this library in an Android Studio project?

Does anyone know what is the compile path that we need to add to gradle in order to reference this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This engine is not something you compile into your project through gradle like regular libraries.

You download the source, build it and "deploy" it onto your phone.

Detailed instructions on how to do that can be found on the [github wiki](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/D8%20on%20Android).

Note that you will need a linux or mac os computer.